# Only one expression can be specified in the select list. in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

this query works fine for me.

```
SELECT (SUM(AveragePrice)/COUNT(1)) AS AveragePrice, SUM(ItemsSold) AS ItemSold ,(SUM(AveragePrice * ItemsSold)) AS TotalSale FROM dbo.tbl_ProductSales
WHERE ProductID IN ( SELECT ProductID FROM tbl_ProductPostions WHERE tbl_ProductPostions.SearchID=3 AND SaleDate='2012-02-02 00:00:00.000')
GROUP BY SaleDate
```

and resuts like this
AveragePrice  | ItemSold | TotalSale

10            | 2        | 2000

but when i embed this query  like this

```
SELECT * ,(SELECT (SUM(AveragePrice)/COUNT(1)) AS AveragePrice, SUM(ItemsSold) AS ItemSold ,(SUM(AveragePrice * ItemsSold)) AS TotalSale FROM dbo.tbl_ProductSales
WHERE ProductID IN ( SELECT ProductID FROM tbl_ProductPostions WHERE tbl_ProductPostions.SearchID=tbl_SearchParameters.SearchID AND SaleDate='2012-02-02 00:00:00.000')
GROUP BY SaleDate )
FROM tbl_SearchParameters
```

i got an error like this.
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

i know i  am crossing the limits but is there any alternate way to do this. 
i know the function can be created to do this task. but is essential to create 
three function separately to compute this these aggregate Average Price,Item Sold,Total Sale?
while i am sure a single query can compute three aggregate for me ?
can any body suggest me proper solution ? i just want to get ride of creating three functions separately for these aggregate respectively. 
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [APPLY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_SearchParameters p
  CROSS APPLY (
               SELECT SUM(AveragePrice/COUNT(1)) AS AveragePrice, 
                      SUM(ItemsSold) AS ItemSold,               
                      SUM(AveragePrice * ItemsSold) AS TotalSale 
               FROM dbo.tbl_ProductSales
               WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID 
                                   FROM tbl_ProductPostions 
                                   WHERE tbl_ProductPostions.SearchID = p.SearchID           
                                     AND SaleDate='2012-02-02 00:00:00.000')
               GROUP BY SaleDate
               ) o
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the second SELECT like:

```
SELECT * ,(SUM(AveragePrice)/COUNT(1)) AS AveragePrice, 
           SUM(ItemsSold) AS ItemSold ,
          (SUM(AveragePrice * ItemsSold)) AS TotalSale 
FROM dbo.tbl_ProductSales
WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID 
                    FROM tbl_ProductPostions 
                    WHERE tbl_ProductPostions.SearchID=tbl_SearchParameters.SearchID 
                    AND SaleDate='2012-02-02 00:00:00.000')
GROUP BY SaleDate )
FROM tbl_SearchParameters
```